# Transformar curl http://IP:PORTA/sendLocalEvent?eventName=_evento em Javafx

Tags: java, libcurl, javafx

Gostaria de fazer um app em javafx , quando se aperta um botão envia um comando do tipo: `curl http://IP:PORTA/sendLocalEvent?eventName=_evento` para um servidor na mesma rede para começar o evento _evento.

Seria usando httpUrlConnection e POST? Como seria?

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso o JavaFX não difere do Java, então se usa o método tradicional mesmo:

```
URL url = new URL("http://IP:PORTA/sendLocalEvent?eventName=_evento");
HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpcon.setDoOutPut(true);
```

Referências:

[How to fire http post request from an javafx client (SOen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321515/how-to-fire-http-post-request-from-an-javafx-client)

[How to send http request getpost in java](http://www.java2blog.com/2016/07/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java.html)